# Testing the ads_management permission for a Facebook app

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I'm building an app that will allow users to export some data in my application to their Facebook Business Manager/Ad Account. For this I need the `ads_management` API. To get this permission, my app needs to go through a review. How do I develop my application without the permission?

I have a `Sandbox Ad Account` but in the `Test Users` menu, I still cannot add the appropriate permission so that when I log-in with the test account, I can make API calls on its behalf.

Am I suppose to put the app in for review before testing it?

Even going to the Graph API explorer, I get the error `Invalid scope: manage_pages`, when I attempt to fetch a `User Access Token` for myself.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure the permissions of your test users in your App Settings under:

`roles > test users`

I also had had trouble doing this. For me the problem was that i already enabled the app (switched it to live mode). In live mode i was unable to configure the permissions. Without getting any information about the reason.

After changing it back into offline mode i was able to do it.

Comment: This also made my implementation unable to redirect the oauth flow to my local dev setup under `http://localhost` since it forces use of https in live mode.